# What is this equal to inside this jquery function?

Tags: jquery

```
function populateTable() {

    // Empty content string
    var tableContent = '';

    // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
    $.getJSON( '/users/userlist', function( data ) {

      // Stick our user data array into a userlist variable in the global object
      userListData = data;

        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
    });
};
```

The code in question is inside the string concatenation section. What is this.username equal to inside the rel= section and how are we string interpolating this in jquery?

this seems to refer to data. Is that correct?

It is not explained well in these docs since $.each here is taking two arguments... data and a callback.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: this refers to data at some index

Comment: The documentation you're looking at is for `each()` when it's called on a jQuery set. You should instead be looking at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ (which is the documentation for the `each()` method on the jQuery object). You'll then find that the `this` value is documented (although admittedly, only in passing).

Comment: The documentation says: _The value can also be accessed through the **this** keyword,_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this keyword is just a reference to the current row although this could be re-written in more understandable way please change below code

```
 $.each(data, function(){
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });
```

to

```
 $.each(data, function(index,dataRow){
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + dataRow.username + '">' + dataRow.username + '</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + dataRow.email + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + dataRow._id + '">delete</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });
```

Where index refers to the index of the each loop and dataRow refers to the row object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since `data` is array of objects `this` points to an individual object inside of this array.

You could also access current object by explicit argument in callback function:

```
$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
    console.log(this === obj);
});
```